# Images not pulled from AWS S3 to heroku nodejs app

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-s3, sails.js

I have a sails nodejs app running on heroku. I have several images that need to be pulled onto the page i.e. logo. When I had images pulled from photobucket everything works. I moved images to AWS S3. Followed https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3. Images are accessible by their link i.e.:https://s3.amazonaws.com/kenguru/main/kglogoweb.png. But not being pulled when page is loaded.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.